# how to restore localhost:8080 from Fitnesse?

Tags: localhost, fitnesse

I installed Fitnesse.jar($using java -jar finesse.jar -p 8080) 
and localhost is occupied by it.
now I want to remove it and restore my localhost when i need localhost for remote debugging in Eclipse.
What can i do with it?

Comment: WHen you say installed, do you mean that you ran it from the command line or did something else?  What OS are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to kill fitnesse (after being ran as a daemon process):

- kill the Java process (kill -9 or through the task manager)
- use the shutdown class/command:

  ```
  java -cp fitnesse.jar fitnesse.Shutdown -h localhost -p 8080
  ```
- use shutdown REST command, via for example wget:

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/?responder=shutdown
  ```